# Android Intent - got crazy

Tags: android, android-intent

OK, I've been programming all day and searched almost everywhere but nothing yet. I hope, you help me a little bit.
I have two activities and I want them to communicate. Here is the code

**MainActivity**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity{

    ImageView imgsettings;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        imgsettings = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgviewsettings);        
        imgsettings.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, AppSettings.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

**Manifest**

```
<application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".AppSettings"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_app_settings" > 
        </activity>
    </application>
```

**AppSettings**

```
package com.example.oldie;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class AppSettings extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

    TextView lblkeyword, txtkeyword;
    TextView lblnumber, txtnumber;
    TextView lbladdress, txtaddress;
    Button btnok;
    String filename = "preferences.txt";
    public static int count = 0;
    private static String keyword = "";


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        lblkeyword = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.lblkeyword);
        txtkeyword = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtkeyword);
        lblnumber = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.lblnumber);
        txtnumber = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtnumber);
        lbladdress = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.lbladdress);
        txtaddress = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtaddress);
        btnok = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnok);

        btnok.setOnClickListener(this);
        lblkeyword.setOnClickListener(this);
        lblnumber.setOnClickListener(this);
        lbladdress.setOnClickListener(this);

        //metritis gia na emfanisei mono mia fora to minima
        if(count==0){
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Tab on the labels for more information", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            count = count + 1;
        }


        updateUIFromFiles();

    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch(v.getId()){
        case R.id.lblkeyword:
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Set a keyword set that will trigger the SMS checker", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            break;
        case R.id.lblnumber:
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Set a number that the app will communicate in case of emmergency", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            break;
        case R.id.lbladdress:
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Set the home address\nex. Agias Lavras 19, Piraeus, Greece", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            break;
        case R.id.btnok:
            if((txtkeyword.getText().toString().equals("")) || (txtaddress.getText().toString().equals("")) ||(txtnumber.getText().toString().equals(""))){
                Toast.makeText(this, "Please fill all the Text Fields.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            else{
                savePreferences();
                keyword = txtkeyword.getText().toString();
                finish();
            }
            break;
        }

    }

    private void savePreferences() {
        //thewrithike anagkaio na apothikeutoun ta stoixeia se ena arxeio gia na mi xathoun.
        try{
            OutputStreamWriter outfile = new OutputStreamWriter(openFileOutput(filename, 0));
            outfile.write(txtkeyword.getText().toString() + "\n" + txtnumber.getText().toString() + "\n" + txtaddress.getText().toString());
            outfile.close();
            Toast.makeText(this, "The contents are saved in the file.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        catch(Throwable t) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Exception: "+t.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
    }

    private void updateUIFromFiles() {
        try { 
            InputStream infile = openFileInput(filename);
            if (infile != null){
                InputStreamReader tmp = new InputStreamReader(infile);
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(tmp);
                txtkeyword.setText(reader.readLine());
                txtnumber.setText(reader.readLine());
                txtaddress.setText(reader.readLine());
                infile.close();
            }
        }
        catch (java.io.FileNotFoundException e) {
        // that's OK, we probably haven't created it yet
        }
        catch (Throwable t) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Exception: "+t.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }

    public String GetMessage(){ //Methodos gia na parei to service to keyword.
        return keyword;
    }

}
```

**The Problem is**

```
06-19 22:17:03.789: E/AndroidRuntime(17204): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-19 22:17:03.789: E/AndroidRuntime(17204): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.oldie/com.example.oldie.AppSettings}: java.lang.NullPointerException
06-19 22:17:03.789: E/AndroidRuntime(17204):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1967)
06-19 22:17:03.789: E/AndroidRuntime(17204):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1992)
06-19 22:17:03.789: E/AndroidRuntime(17204):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:127)
06-19 22:17:03.789: E/AndroidRuntime(17204):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1158)
06-19 22:17:03.789: E/AndroidRuntime(17204):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
06-19 22:17:03.789: E/AndroidRuntime(17204):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
06-19 22:17:03.789: E/AndroidRuntime(17204):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4441)
06-19 22:17:03.789: E/AndroidRuntime(17204):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-19 22:17:03.789: E/AndroidRuntime(17204):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
06-19 22:17:03.789: E/AndroidRuntime(17204):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
06-19 22:17:03.789: E/AndroidRuntime(17204):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
06-19 22:17:03.789: E/AndroidRuntime(17204):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
06-19 22:17:03.789: E/AndroidRuntime(17204): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
06-19 22:17:03.789: E/AndroidRuntime(17204):    at com.example.oldie.AppSettings.onCreate(AppSettings.java:39)
06-19 22:17:03.789: E/AndroidRuntime(17204):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1049)
06-19 22:17:03.789: E/AndroidRuntime(17204):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1931)
06-19 22:17:03.789: E/AndroidRuntime(17204):    ... 11 more
```

The code for the Intent doesn't work at all. My app crashes and ends. I'm one step before taking pills to control my anger... I' don't know what's wrong and the intent doesn't work. Please help me.

Comment: post AppSettings as well.

Comment: The imgsettings variable has got an id inside and it's not null because I have tested the exact code with a toast when I click the imageview (without the lines of the intent) and it works perfectly.

Comment: Post the error you are getting.

Comment: Post the full logcat.

Comment: The whole stack trace. That's like a needle in a haystack.

Comment: I posted it. Sorry for not being a picture. The site doesn't let me to do so.

Comment: Whatever is at line 39 of `AppSettings` hasn't been initialized

Comment: I saw that too codeMagic, but in those lines there is this code:
37 - btnok = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnok);
38 -
39 -  btnok.setOnClickListener(this);
40 -  lblkeyword.setOnClickListener(this);

Comment: Yeah so `btnok` is `null`. Probably because you're using the wrong layout as one of the answers points out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the AppSettings activity, you are setting the content view to R.layout.activity_main.  I'm guessing that not what you intended.  It probably does not have the TextViews your expect to find. The calls to find them return null, which causes the exception when you invoke setOnClickListener().

Answer (score 0):

I can't be sure what the problem exactly is without a logcat, but here are some things you can try:

1.) Try using getApplicationContext() instead of MyActivity.this in your Intent constructor.

2.) Check if the AppSettings class is in the same package as your MainActivity class.

I'd try to help more if you post a relevant logcat

Comment: Number 1...no. Activity Context should be used there (should also be used in the Toast)

Comment: I have posted the logcat too in the original message.

Comment: and the AppSettings is inside the same package as my mainactivity

Comment: The problem is in the onCreate() method of your AppSettings class. Check line number 39 in your AppSettings class (that's the line that the logcat is pointing to).

Comment: E/AndroidRuntime(17204):    at com.example.oldie.AppSettings.onCreate(AppSettings.java:39).    This line at your logcat might help you solve the problem

Comment: What it means is that the NullPointerException occurred at line no. 39 in your AppSettings class

Answer (score 0):

You're using the wrong layout in your `AppSettings` activity:

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
```

That's the same as your `MainActivity`, which is probably not right. As a result you're button isn't found here:

```
btnok = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnok);
```

and subsequently will be null and when you try to set an onClickListener here:

```
btnok.setOnClickListener(this);
```

you get the `NullPointerException`.